# I want to find common factor of two number count value?

Tags: java

Code:

```
public static void main(String... args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count =0;
    int a= sc.nextInt();
    int b =sc.nextInt();
    if(a>b){
        //int count =0;
        for(int i =1;i<=a;i++){
            if(a/i == 0 && b/i == 0){
                count++;
                System.out.println(count);
            }
        }
    }else if(a<b){
        //int count =0;
        for(int i=1;i<=b;i++){
            if(a/i == 0 && b/i == 0){
                count++;
                System.out.println(count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. I am not getting any output what is error?
2. I want to take input from user and then find the  number of common factors.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should try to fix your formatting, particularly the code indentation. You definitely shouldn't have multiple close braces on one line, because it makes it a lot harder to see the code blocks. If you weren't aware that this was good practice, have a read of the [Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html).

Comment: You need to check/learn basic math: are there ANY numbers where you can divide them and get 0 as an answer? `a/i = 0` -> `a = 0 * i` -> `a = 0`.

Comment: @MarcB I was thinking that as well, but it's integer division, so if the division results in a number less than 1 then the result will be 0. Although in this program that will never happen since the loop conditions.

Comment: I know maths. and my input will starts from 1 not 0.

Comment: ok, so the user enters 10 and 12. `10/1 == 0 && 12/1 == 0` -> `10 ==0 && 12 == 0` -> `false && false`. then for i=2, `10/2 == 0 && 12/2 == 0` -> `5 == 0 && 6 == 0` -> `false && false`. doesn't matter where you start your `i` loop from, you're testing the WRONG values.

Comment: the proper test is to do a modulo division. if `a mod i && b mod i` both produce zeroes, THEN you have a common divisor.

Comment: Thanks I came to know where I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: thanks Marc, i got that

Comment: Are you looking for the greatest common factor? Because Euclid's algorithm is a really easy implementation for GCD.

Answer (score 1):

Lets be more precise.
If a < b then simple test for 
1. numbers<=a/2
2. whether a divide b
3. if any number is zero no need to find factors simply count 0
as shown here,

```
   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    long n = s.nextLong();   
    long m=s.nextLong();
    int small=0;
    int count=0;

    if(n==0 || m==0){
        System.out.println(count);
        return;

    }

    if(n<m) 
       small=(int)n/2;
   else
    small=(int)m/2;

     count=1;

    for(int i=2;i<=small;i++){
        if(n%i==0 && m%i==0)
        count++;
    }
   if(n%m==0 || m%n==0)count++;

    System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if((a/i == 0)&&(b/i == 0))
```

This condition is wrong -- `a / i` will only ever be zero if `a` is zero, or if it's less than `i`. This is clearly not what you want.

What you need here is the modulus operator, `%`, which returns the remainder when dividing its two operands by each other.

```
if((a%i == 0)&&(b%i == 0))
```

With this change made in both locations, your program appears to work correctly.